# Как передать данные в скрипт PHP из HTML?

Tags: php, html

Вопрос следующий имеется страничка на HTML в ней есть поля для логина и пароля для подключения к БД. Как передать вводимые данные в скрипт?

Comment: Отправить форму или аяксом

Comment: А можете дать ссылку на тему ajax?

Comment: Скрипт на клиентской или серверной стороне? Если на клиентской — повесьте на форму обработчик события `onsubmit`. Если на серверной — то как написал выше @KonstantinOkhotnick (отправка формы приведёт к отображению новой страницы, возвращаемой сервером в ответ, а AJAX используется при необходимости модификации страницы без её перезагрузки).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передать можно с помощью [суперглобальных массивов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php) `$_GET` и `$_POST`. Метод передачи можно выставить в самой форме `<form action="/index.php" method="post">` где `action="/index.php"` это пусть к файлу который получает данные из формы. В файле (`index.php` к примеру) будет следующий код.

Форма `html` для `$_POST` :

```
<form action='/index.php' method='post'>
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="save" >
</form>
```

`PHP` код `index.php`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
 echo $_POST['password'].'<br>';
 echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

Если одним файлом, то можно записать следующим образом (файл `index.php`):

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
     echo $_POST['password'].'<br>';
     echo $_POST['name'];
    }
?>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form action='/index.php' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="save" >
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Да. также можно и через `AJAX`, отправляя `JSON`.

Вот рабочий пример реализации `ajax` с помощью `jquery` файл `index.php`:

```
<?php

function is_ajax()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

if (is_ajax() && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {

    echo json_encode(array(
        'ok' => 'AJAX OK!!!'
    ));
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="sub" action='/index.php' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="save" >
    </form>


<script>
   $("document").ready(function(){
    $("#sub").submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();

       var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "index.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(r) {
              console.log(r);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>


 </body>
</html>
```

С помощью `echo json_encode(array('ok' => 'AJAX OK!!!'));` мы отправляем ответ нашему браузеру и в панели разработчика можем увидеть ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно обратить внимание что пароли и важные данные принято передавать `post` методом.

Comment: А скажите, выше писали, что это все можно сделать через Jquery?

Comment: да, на jquery пишется код для вызова ajax и отправки json методами post или get

Comment: А не могли бы вы дать ссылку на пример? Был очень признателен.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/ref_httpmethods.asp `get` и `post` это `http` методы, они используются во всех язиках программирования для `web` где есть сервер и вебсайт или сервис для передачи данных по `http`. Отличие AJAX от обычной отправки в том что AJAX работает без перезагрузки страницы. Можно использовать AJAX и на JQuery и на обычном джаваскрипте.

Comment: Добавил рабочий пример ajax с помощью jquery

Comment: Спасибо! Очень конструктивно!