# Подключение JS к MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, база-данных

Мне нужно подключить JS к MySQL. То есть с помощью javascript добавлять, считывать или удалять элементы таблици в MySQL.
Желательно дать код с комментариями или ссылку на статью/урок об этом.

Comment: JS какой где?..

Comment: через js ни как,попробуй ajax а вообще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16318/javascript-mysql

Answer (score 4):

[MySQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) это технология которая работает на стороне сервера. [Джаваскрипт](https://learn.javascript.ru/) работает на стороне клиента в браузере. Стак технологий может быть таким: PHP, MySQL, [Javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/), HTML. PHP это серверный язык программирования. С помощью PHP создается подключение к базе на стороне сервера (хостинга). Для начала рекомендую освоить HTML и JS или начать с PHP, а затем уже MySQL. До того как отправить в базу что либо нужно разобратся с технологиями которые делают эту отправку. Важно помнить что Javascript отрабатывается в браузере клиента (ПК, смартфон...). На стороне сервера может быть использован серверный язык программирования такой как PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, Go... Рекомендую PHP т.к. у него порог вхождения ниже и его легче освоить в сравнении с Java и [Go](https://golang.org/), к примеру.

Ниже я скинул ссылки по стаку технологий [PHP](http://php.net/), JS, MySQL:

[Как передать данные в скрипт PHP из HTML?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625453/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-php-%D0%B8%D0%B7-html/625492#625492)

[Вывод из БД без перезагрузки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627014/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%91%D0%94-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8/627030#627030)

[javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

[PHP](http://php.net/)

**Более Advanced рекомендация:**

Также рекомендую обратить внимание на CRUD (create, read, update, delete) концепцию в программировании. В двух словах это создание, чтение, обновление и удаление данных с помощью готовых библиотек (или модулей) во фреймворке. Ниже ссылка "[что такое фреймворк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA)". На всех выше перечисленных PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, Go есть свои фреймворки. Со своими CRUD.

Если вы вдруг имели ввиду [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) вместо Javascript тогда в этом [направлении](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/).

Comment: Mike, вполне возможно